# Query can't find saved item using afterInsert

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

I have a Grails application using GORM to save a Note domain object.

I can successfully save the Note object but when I query the collection containing the object using afterInsert it doesn't find the object. When I query the collection manually I can see the object has been created. Is there any reason why this is occurring? I can't see why.

**Note**

```
def afterInsert(){
    println(id) //prints the id as expected. Matches the database
    def persisted = getDB().notes.findOne(id)
    println(persisted)
            //returns null
}
```

**NoteService**

```
noteInstance.save(flush: true, failOnError: true))
```

Comment: no joy with the withNewSession closure. Hard to find the root of the problem

Comment: Hi Travis, I have the same problem. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Abincepto it's been a while since I worked on the issue. I didn't find a solution using the afterinsert block. I manually did the call in the calling class after calling the save function. It works but the code isn't as clean

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just created a new question with my problem.